# MySQL subquery conversion

Tags: mysql, variables, join, subquery

For the query below I need it re-write it so that I can utilize a variable in place of the "parcel_number" value.

Because I'm using a sub-query currently, I can't use a variable which can pass through (to my knowledge). I've looked for hours and can't find a definite reason subqueries can't have variables passed into them, so I take that as a "no".

I'm super rusty at this, so feel free to laugh if my code below is inefficient or otherwise. I just am in major need of some assistance. Please advise:

**/* Selects all records where the conditions below are met */**

```
select *
from master_township_uniformity
where living_area_square_foot
between @low_range and @high_range
```

**/* Pulls in properties where "neighborhood code" is same */**

```
AND
neighborhood_code =
(
select neighborhood_code
from master_township_uniformity
where parcel_number = '0621115027'
)
```

**/* Pulls in properties where "full and half bath" is same */**

```
AND
full_and_half_bath = 
(
select full_and_half_bath
from master_township_uniformity
where parcel_number = '0621115027'
)
```

Comment: What is your query supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Rusty? Have a refresh on JOINs.

Comment: Thanks @PM77-1 for reformatting my question. I'm brand-new here and completely overlooked that option.

Answer (score 1):

Using a join to the same table with an alias we can filter the results and eliminate the sub queries. I believe this should work for you.

mtu - is your original master_township_uniformity table

mtuParcel -  is a duplicate of that table that you can use to filter by the parcel number

We join the two tables on the neighborhood_code and full_and_half_bath fields to filter the results to only matching values.

```
SELECT mtu.*
FROM master_township_uniformity AS mtu
  INNER JOIN master_township_uniformity AS mtuParcel
  ON mtu.neighborhood_code = mtuParcel.neighborhood_code
  AND mtu.full_and_half_bath = mtuParcel.full_and_half_bath
WHERE mtuParcel.parcel_number = '0621115027'
  AND mtu.living_area_square_foot
    BETWEEN @low_range AND @high_range
```

Comment: You are a life-saver @Darren. Thanks for breaking that down so that it was relatively easy to understand. All of this time I was opting for subqueries over joins because they were easier for me to read. But now I have a better understanding and your code worked like a charm. Thanks again!